# how to add jars to remote repository and then access it?

Tags: maven

I want to add a dependency from the remote repository to pom.xml but it gives me artifact missing error.

I have created folders structure in the remote repository. I have put actual jxl.jar file in a folder named as "1" for version & put that into a folder named as "jxl" created for artifact and put that also in another folder named as "jxl" for groupId .

Here is the code which I added to pom.xml :

```
<repositories>
      <repository>
         <id>uirepo</id>
         <url>http://xx.yy.zz.ss/uirepo</url>
      </repository>
   </repositories>

<dependencies>
     <dependency>
          <groupId>jxl</groupId>
          <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
          <version>1</version>
      </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

But getting error of missing artifact

Comment: Don't you use a repository manager like Nexus or Artifactory?

Comment: "I have created folders structure in the remote repository." <- How did you do this? Be specific.

Comment: No. I am not using the repository manager, Is that necessary?

Comment: I have created a folder structure in the server within VPN and that reflects in hosted repository.

Answer (score 0):

Just making the folder structure and putting the jar in the right place is not enough.

**The best thing to do is to use a repository manager**. [Here](https://maven.apache.org/repository-management.html) you have a list of both open source and commercial ones.

If you have good reasons not to use one, you may be able to mimic it. [This article](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/build-tools/apache-maven/maven-repository-on-ftp-server.html) demonstrates how to upload (via FTP) and then consume artifacts form remote server without a repository manager. It will give you some hints what Maven expects to find at given location (apart from the jar itself).

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the result that you have to take groupId as the outer folder then take artifactId as exact name(without version) of the jar and which should be the inner folder of groupId then version folder whichever it is but within artifact folder and then exact jar within it with version mentioned in the name of jar after dash(-) like:'jxl-1'.